# Foreign Key Reference Error for Azure Data Sync

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

In My Data Sync Group there have 2 tables . Let say **A** and **B** . some columns of **A** reference to **B** table. **B** is Master Table.

When sync occur table **A** is do the processing ahead of Table **B**. So I got the Foreign Key Reference Error.

IS Azure Data sync processing with alphabetic order ?
Any solution for this ?

Thz in advance.

Comment: Data Sync Service should automatically detect the FK relationship and sync the parent table first. i suggest you post error and the tracing id to the SQL Azure forum so the product team can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

As @JuneT suggested, you might want to post this question in the "[SQL Azure Forum](http://aka.ms/sqlazureforum)" (http://aka.ms/sqlazureforum).  When you do, they have asked specifically that you include the following information when asking Data Sync related questions:

**Server id**: Your server id

**Region**: Where your Data Sync Server is located/created

**Time / Date**: Date and time when you encountered the issue

**Tracing Id**: The tracing id you see in the message in UI